# Cleaning messy text from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with news information (headlines, dates, authors, etc). The column #7 is the content of the news articles. I need to clean that content because when I scraped the information from the news website the articles came with lots of messy data.

**Here are two examples of the content I need to clean**

```
dput(subset_silla_kwords_clean[10,7])
"\n.cualq {\n\twidth:712px;\n}\n\nh1 {\n\tcolor:#f05927;\n}\n\n#foto {\n\twidth:95px;\n\theight:95px;\n\tbackground-color:#ccc;\n\tfloat:left;\n}\n#foto .snap {\n\tpadding:10px;\n\tclear:both;\n\theight:auto;\n}\n#texto {\n\twidth:256px;\n\tbackground-color:#ebebeb;\n\tfloat:left;\n\tfont-size:12px;\n\tcolor:#000;\n\tmargin-bottom:10px;\n\tmargin-right:10px;\n\tmin-height:95px;\n}\n#texto .snap {\n\tpadding:10px;\n\tclear:both;\n\theight:auto;\n}\n#texto h1{\n\tfont-size:14px;\n\tfont-weight:bold;\n\tmargin:0px 0px 5px 0px;\n\tpadding:0px;}\n#texto2 {\n\twidth:256px;\n\tbackground-color:#ebebeb;\n\tfloat:left;\n\tfont-size:12px;\n\tcolor:#000;\n\tmargin-bottom:10px;\n\tmin-height:95px;\n}\n#texto2 .snap {\n\tpadding:10px;\n\tclear:both;\n\theight:auto;\n}\n#texto2 h1{\n\tfont-size:14px;\n\tfont-weight:bold;\n\tmargin:0px 0px 5px 0px;\n\tpadding:0px;}\n.climpiar {\n\tclear:both;\n\theight:5px;\n}\n#proceso {\n\tclear:both;\n\twidth:712px;\n}\n\n\nla negociación que arrancó ayer estará sujeta a todo tipo de influencias. estos son los personajes que -sin necesariamente pertenecer a las farc- podrían tener mayor incidencia del lado de la guerrilla.\n\n                                               \n\n\n\n\n\n\niván márquez, comandante del bloque caribe\nel comandante del bloque caribe y segundo al mando de las farc es una pieza clave en estos diálogos porque es quien maneja las relaciones internacionales y con venezuela. aunque comanda el bloque más pobre y más disminuido militarmente, es junto con timochenko el único de esta generación de guerrilleros que fue elegido por conferencia, lo que le da bastante legitimidad por ser uno de los “históricos”.  márquez fue parlamentario de la unión patriótica y es de la generación de guerrilleros formada por el conflicto en caquetá.\n\n\n\n\n\n\njesús santrich, el ideólogo.\nsantrich ha llegado a ser el ideólogo no solo del bloque caribe y la comisión internacional sino también de los movimientos sociales cercanos a las farc. \nsu influencia se nota sobre todo en el cambio de estilo en la comunicación y el lenguaje de la guerrilla.\n \n\n\n \n\n\n\n\n\ntimochenko, el comandante\nes el de mayor antigüedad en las farc salvo martín villa y el sargento pascuas y es el símbolo de la unidad y de la cohesión.  trazó con alias ‘mauricio’ las líneas generales de inicio del diálogo.  asumió la responsabilidad de dar el paso de la negociación, además de ser el delegado del secretariado en el bloque del magdalena medio. tiene a su favor haber resistido toda la ofensiva en el catatumbo lo que le otorga el respeto de los guerrilleros por ser un buen combatiente. \n \n\n\n\n\n\n\npablo catatumbo, el poder oculto\nes el comandante de más prestigio militar. es el sucesor de 'cano' en el comando conjunto de occidente, llamado ahora bloque alfonso cano. su importancia radica en haber cambiado la estrategia militar de las farc, que ha pasado de tener como eje la cordillera oriental a la central y tener la retaguardia en el pacífico. también fue el responsable de la ofensiva militar en el cauca. es uno de los grandes ideológos de las farc y es quien está detrás de las críticas a la doctrina de la seguridad nacional. su delegado en la mesa es el sargento pascuas, que es el último de los marquetalianos.\n\n \n\n\n\n\n\ncarlos lozano, por el respeto que le tienen a su lucha\nlozano no solo es dirigente histórico del partido comunista sino que es el director del semanario voz, que es una de las tribunas más importantes de la izquierda. y además, es vocero de la marcha patriótica y miembro de colombianos por la paz. estuvo en la comisión de notables de los diálogos del caguán y aunque él nunca lo ha confirmado, al parecer tuvo incidencia en los primeros encuentros entre el gobierno y las farc porque conoce a timochenko desde la época en que militaron juntos en la juco.\nlozano, como el representante a la cámara iván cepeda, son personas que pueden poner sobre la mesa ideas importantes para el proceso.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nel paisa oscar, comandante de la columna móvil teófilo forero\neste guerrillero es una de las fichas que podría sabotear el proceso. está a cargo de la columna móvil teófilo forero, que es la fuerza militar élite y más sanguinaria de las farc. el paisa fue el responsable del atentado al club el nogal. \n \n\n\n \n\n\n \n\n                                               \n\n\n\n\n\n\nhugo chávez, por ser el garante.\nalias rodrigo granda y andrés paris se entrevistaron con chávez desde comienzos del 2011 para hablar de posibilidades del proceso de paz. también, según contó vincens fisas, antes de la reunión en cuba, chávez tuvo una reunión de ocho horas con timochenko en venezuela que habría influido para que las farc “se moderaran”. chávez representa para las farc una garantía en la mesa de negociación, además de que su gobierno es un modelo para ellos.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nraúl castro, el que ayuda, les da apoyo logístico, y la experiencia.\nel presidente cubano juega un papel fundamental porque las dos partes confían en él. cuba no solo presta la logística para los encuentros, sino que sirvió como anfitrión durante la primera etapa y ayudó a que se mantuvieran en secreto las negociaciones. \"sin la preocupación y tesón del gobierno presidido por el comandante raúl castro, esta larga faena no habría llegado a tan exitoso puerto,\" dijo 'timochenko' en su video del 4 de septiembre, cuando confirmó la existencia de diálogos entre el gobierno y las farc.\n\n\n \n\n\n \n\n                                               \n\n\n\n\n\n\njoaquín gómez, la incógnita\nla posición de joaquín gómez, jefe del bloque sur, con presencia en caquetá y putumayo, es la gran incógnita del proceso. es el único del secretariado que no ha hecho ningún pronunciamiento público sobre el proceso de paz. gómez fue el que hizo las alianzas políticas con los farcpolíticos del caquetá y es el hombre del narcotráfico. su bloque es el más rico de las farc y también uno de los más poderosos militarmente. su oposición al proceso puede ser complicado para los que están sentados en la mesa.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\npiedad córdoba\ncomo líder de la marcha patriótica y fundadora de colombianos y colombianas por la paz es la persona que más se ha jugado personalmente para tender un puente hacia las farc. internacionalmente, también ella ha buscado abrirle un espacio político a la guerrilla y es quien pone en la agenda pública temas que son fundamentales para ellos. las farc confían en ella, la mencionaron en el discurso de ayer, y curiosamente, también ha tendido un puente hacia los jefes paramilitares que han terminado viendo en ella también una persona que podría abogar a favor de ellos en la mesa de negociación.\n\n\n \n \n\n\n \n"                                          

dput(subset_silla_kwords_clean[1,7])
".img-container {display:none;}\nhoy el ministro de defensa, luis carlos villegas, reveló los 29 municipios en los que habrá lugares de concentración para las farc después de la firma de un acuerdo final. la silla revisó esos municipios para ver cómo votan y en cuáles hay otros factores de conflicto.\nrevisamos la información por municipios, porque ese es el dato que se hizo público hoy. sin embargo, los lugares de concentración serán áreas de máximo 5 kilómetros cuadrados, y por eso lo que encontramos puede referirse a zonas más o menos cerca de los lugares de concentración. cuando se conozcan las veredas en las que estarán las zonas y campamentos intentaremos hacer este cruce con más precisión.\ninstrucciones: haga clic sobre las pestañas para ver como es la situación actual de estos municipios\n\n\n                    var divelement = document.getelementbyid('viz1470407285572');                    var vizelement = divelement.getelementsbytagname('object')[0];                    vizelement.style.width='724px';vizelement.style.height='899px';                    var scriptelement = document.createelement('script');                    scriptelement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizelement.parentnode.insertbefore(scriptelement, vizelement);                \n\n\n                    var divelement = document.getelementbyid('viz1470407448990');                    var vizelement = divelement.getelementsbytagname('object')[0];                    vizelement.style.width='319px';vizelement.style.height='599px';                    var scriptelement = document.createelement('script');                    scriptelement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizelement.parentnode.insertbefore(scriptelement, vizelement);                \n\n\n                    var divelement = document.getelementbyid('viz1470407448990');                    var vizelement = divelement.getelementsbytagname('object')[0];                    vizelement.style.width='319px';vizelement.style.height='599px';                    var scriptelement = document.createelement('script');                    scriptelement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizelement.parentnode.insertbefore(scriptelement, vizelement);                \n \nen conclusión, muchos luagres estarán en municpios de alcaldes liberales, en la mayoría hay comunidades afro o resguardos indígenas, y más o menos la mitad tienen cultivos ilícitos, presencia de otros grupos armados y minería ilegal.\n \n\n\ndabeiba, antioquia\neste municipio que es la puerta de entrada al urabá antioqueño, es el corredor entre el nudo de paramillo y chocó. y hay presencia de farc y de minería ilegal, principalmente de oro.\n\n \n\n\nituango, antioquia\nen este municipio del norte de antioquia hay presencia de minería ilegal de oro que explotan las farc y bacrim para financiarse. el municipio fue víctima de la violencia de los paramilitares del bloque mineros, especialmente con la masacre del aro. además, en su territorio actualmente se construye la represa e hidroeléctrica de ituango, a cargo epm y que va en un 50 por ciento de avance y entraría a operar en 2018.\n\n \n\n\nremedios, antioquia\neste municipio del nordeste antioqueño hay algo de coca, y minería de oro. allí, además de las farc hay presencia de eln y bacrim, especialmente del clan úsuga que el año pasado mató a cuatro personas de una misma familia.\n\n \n\n\nvigía del fuerte, antioquia\neste municipio que bordea el río atrato es uno de los más pobres de antioquia. es muy cercano a la vereda de bojayá donde las farc cometieron la masacre de la iglesia.\n\n \n\n\narauquita, arauca\neste municipio fronterizo con venezuela ha sido azotado históricamente por las farc pero en los últimos años han hecho alianza estratégica con el eln. este año, la defensoría alertó por el aumento de asesinatos selectivos y explosión de petardos atribuídos especialmente al eln. hay algunos cultivos de coca y algo de minería ilegal aunque lo importante aquí, como en el resto de arauca son las explotaciones petroleras.\n\n \n\n\ntame, arauca\nmunicipio con presencia histórica del eln, que en los últimos años ha hecho alianza estratégica con las farc. hay pocos cultivos de coca y más bien lo que ha atraído a los ilegales es la explotación petrolera.\n\n \n\n\ncartagena del chairá, caquetá\nubicado en el centro del departamento de caquetá, allí tanto las farc como los cultivos de coca han sido históricos, sobre todo hacia la cordillera.\n\n \n\n\nla montañita, caquetá\neste fue uno de los municipios de consolidación en la era uribe aunque sin mucho éxito. hoy sigue siendo uno de los que más ha aumentado en hectáreas de coca en el país, además de uno donde más constantemente la fuerza pública hace incautaciones de material de guerra de las farc, como el que realizó en febrero donde se encontraron 100 kilos de explosivos.\n\n \n\n\nsan vicente del caguán, caquetá\nel municipio donde se ubicó la zona de distensión de las farc en los diálogos con el expresidente andrés pastrana vuelve a quedar entre los municipios protagonistas en este proceso. ha tenido presencia histórica de la columna teófilo forero de las farc, que se financia sobre todo a través de la extorsión. de hecho, este año se supo que la fiscalía tenía listas 300 órdenes de captura para combatir a los encargados de cobrar las vacunas, como contó semana.\n\n \n\n\nbuenos aires, cauca\neste municipio del norte del departamento se llenó de periodistas hace un año luego de que las farc asesinaran, mientras dormían, a 11 soldados. ese hecho hizo revertir la decisión de suspender los bombardeos contra la guerrilla y puso en jaque el proceso de paz. en marzo de este año los jefes de las farc marcos calarcá y pablo catatumbo fueron allí a hacer pedagogía de los acuerdos. hay presencia de coca, sobre todo en los límites con el valle del cauca y minería ilegal de oro con 53 minas pequeñas y 11 medianas donde trabajan unos mil 500 mineros.\n\n \n\n\ncaldono, cauca\ncaldono ha sido víctima de las farc 68 veces desde 1996. la estación de policía ha sido destruida tres veces. aunque hay cultivos de coca, son de baja densidad. el 80 por ciento de la población es indígena.\n\n \n\n\ncorinto, cauca\ncorinto es un municipio que sirve de corredor entre los ríos magdalena y cauca y por eso las farc se han ensañado allí. por ejemplo, sólo en 2009 hubo una docena de hostigamientos y hasta ese año, la guerrilla se lo había tomado siete veces. hasta 2013, según verdad abierta, había habido 5 masacres. hay algo de pequeña y mediana minería ilegal de material de construcción y de oro.\n\n \n\n\nla paz, cesar\neste municipio de la serranía del perijá tuvo presencia y peleas por el territorio entre farc, eln y los paramilitares. además, hay al menos dos resguardos indígenas. uno de los corregimientos más azotadas por el conflicto es san josé de oriente, que queda a sólo 20 kilómetros de la frontera con venezuela y donde sólo hasta el 2006 volvió a instalarse una estación de policía.\n\n \n\n\nriosucio, chocó\neste municipio del urabá chocoano tiene una corta frontera con el chocó y una larga con antioquia. ha tenido presencia de guerrilla y paramilitares, poblaciones indígenas y afro y graves problemas de necesidades básicas insatisfechas.\n\n \n\n\ntierralta, córdoba\naunque tierralta es conocido por haber alojado la concentración de los paramilitares en santa fe ralito, ahora tendrá un campamento en la lejana vereda de el gallo, donde hay presencia de las farc y de bacrim. el gallo queda junto a la represa de urrá y en el parque natural del nudo de paramillo, que ha sido zona de refugio de grupos ilegales y corredor para el tráfico de armas y de drogas.\n\n \n\n\npuerto colombia, guainía\neste corregimiento departamental (una entidad que depende del departamento y no tiene alcalde propio) es esencialmente selvático. con algunos cultivos de coca. en él, como en buena parte de la amazonía, hay amplios resguardos indígenas.\n\n \n\n\nfonseca, guajira\nese municipio de la zona de la guajira conocida como \"la provincia\" es conocido porque allí queda el corregimiento de conejo, donde las farc hicieron proselitismo armado a inicios de 2015. en su zona urbana hicieron presencia los paramilitares mientras que en la que queda en las estribaciones de la sierra del perijá hacían presencia las farc.\n\n \n\n\nsan josé del guaviare, guaviare\nla capital del guaviare y el único municipio que tendrá dos zonas de concentración, es el décimo municipio con más coca sembrada en todo el país. en él han operado varios frentes, como el séptimo. las farc dinamitaron la recientemente pavimentada carretera hacia el centro del país después de anunciar el cese al fuego unilateral en 2014,\n\n \n\n\nla macarena, meta\nuno de los municipios que conformó la zona de distensión que le entregó el gobierno de andrés pastrana a las farc entre 1999 y 2002, en él está buena parte del parque natural de la sierra de la macarena.\n\n \n\n\nmapiripán, meta\neste municipio, que se hizo famoso por la masacre de paramilitares del urabá en 1997, tiene presencia de bandas criminales. hasta hace pocos años está conectada por vía pavimentada con villavicencio y san josé del guaviare.\n\n \n\n\nmesetas, meta\nmunicipio del ariari, hizo parte de la zona de distensión que le entregó el gobierno de andrés pastrana a las farc entre 1999 y 2002. como sus vecinos, votó por el uribismo en 2014 y tiene cultivos ilícitos.\n\n \n\n\nvistahermosa, meta\neste municipio de la sierra de la macarena, en el que queda parte del parque natural de ese nombre, tiene una presencia tradicional de las farc y fue parte de la zona de distensión que le entregó el gobierno de andrés pastrana a las farc entre 1999 y 2002. las farc no parecen tener mucha tracción política, pues votó por el uribismo en 2014. tiene cultivos de coca.\n\n \n\n\npolicarpa, nariño\nun pequeño munuicipio andino pero con varios corregimientos en la selva pacífica, en policarpa hubo presencia muy fuerte de las farc (con el frente 29) y los paramilitares (con el frente libertadores del sur, luengo la llamada ong y finalmente los rastrojos), hasta el punto de que los dos atacaron en diferentes momentos el cuartel de policía y hace menos de 4 año hubo desplazamientos grandes de las veredad de puerto rico, montañita y campo alegre, según verdad abierta.\n\n \n\n\ntumaco, nariño\ntumaco, el segundo puerto del país sobre el pacífico, es el municipio con más cultivos de coca de todo el país, y además sirve de corredor estratégico para organizaciones criminales, pues es -al mismo tiempo- puerto de embarque, frontera y centro de tráfico de insumos químicos para la producción de cocaína. y, aunque hay presencia de bacrim, las farc son más poderosas, especialmente su columna móvil daniel aldana.\n\n \n\n\ntibú, norte de santander\nla capital del catatumbo es un tradicional pueblo petrolero. allí queda la gabarra, un corregimiento conocido por una masacre paramilitar en 1999, y las farc hacen presencia especialmente en ese corregimiento y en otro llamado pacelli.
```

**Here is the approach I am using so far**

```
#To eliminate words that contains numbers
subset_silla_kwords_clean[1,7] <- trimws(gsub("\\w*[0-9]+\\w*\\s*", "", subset_silla_kwords_clean[1,7]))

#To eliminate everything except alphanumeric characters, preserving some punctuation. 
subset_silla_kwords_clean[1,7] <- gsub("[^[:alnum:][:blank:]//.\"?&/\\-]", "", subset_silla_kwords_clean[1,7])

#The content looks much better, but still messy
subset_silla_kwords_clean[1,7]
[1] ".img-container displaynonehoy el ministro de defensa luis carlos villegas reveló los municipios en los que habrá lugares de concentración para las farc después de la firma de un acuerdo final. la silla revisó esos municipios para ver cómo votan y en cuáles hay otros factores de conflicto.revisamos la información por municipios porque ese es el dato que se hizo público hoy. sin embargo los lugares de concentración serán áreas de máximo kilómetros cuadrados y por eso lo que encontramos puede referirse a zonas más o menos cerca de los lugares de concentración. cuando se conozcan las veredas en las que estarán las zonas y campamentos intentaremos hacer este cruce con más precisión.instrucciones haga clic sobre las pestañas para ver como es la situación actual de estos municipios                    var divelement  document.var vizelement  divelement.vizelement.style..style.var scriptelement  document.createelementscript                    scriptelement.src  https//public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/.js                    vizelement.parentnode.insertbeforescriptelement vizelement                                    var divelement  document.var vizelement  divelement.vizelement.style..style.var scriptelement  document.createelementscript                    scriptelement.src  https//public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/.js                    vizelement.parentnode.insertbeforescriptelement vizelement                                    var divelement  document.var vizelement  divelement.vizelement.style..style.var scriptelement  document.createelementscript                    scriptelement.src  https//public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/.js                    vizelement.parentnode.insertbeforescriptelement vizelement                 en conclusión muchos luagres estarán en municpios de alcaldes liberales en la mayoría hay comunidades afro o resguardos indígenas y más o menos la mitad tienen cultivos ilícitos presencia de otros grupos armados y minería ilegal. dabeiba antioquiaeste municipio que es la puerta de entrada al urabá antioqueño es el corredor entre el nudo de paramillo y chocó. y hay presencia de farc y de minería ilegal principalmente de oro. ituango antioquiaen este municipio del norte de antioquia hay presencia de minería ilegal de oro que explotan las farc y bacrim para financiarse. el municipio fue víctima de la violencia de los paramilitares del bloque mineros especialmente con la masacre del aro. además en su territorio actualmente se construye la represa e hidroeléctrica de ituango a cargo epm y que va en un por ciento de avance y entraría a operar en . remedios antioquiaeste municipio del nordeste antioqueño hay algo de coca y minería de oro. allí además de las farc hay presencia de eln y bacrim especialmente del clan úsuga que el año pasado mató a cuatro personas de una misma familia. vigía del fuerte antioquiaeste municipio que bordea el río atrato es uno de los más pobres de antioquia. es muy cercano a la vereda de bojayá donde las farc cometieron la masacre de la iglesia. arauquita araucaeste municipio fronterizo con venezuela ha sido azotado históricamente por las farc pero en los últimos años han hecho alianza estratégica con el eln. este año la defensoría alertó por el aumento de asesinatos selectivos y explosión de petardos atribuídos especialmente al eln. hay algunos cultivos de coca y algo de minería ilegal aunque lo importante aquí como en el resto de arauca son las explotaciones petroleras. tame araucamunicipio con presencia histórica del eln que en los últimos años ha hecho alianza estratégica con las farc. hay pocos cultivos de coca y más bien lo que ha atraído a los ilegales es la explotación petrolera. cartagena del chairá caquetáubicado en el centro del departamento de caquetá allí tanto las farc como los cultivos de coca han sido históricos sobre todo hacia la cordillera. la montañita caquetáeste fue uno de los municipios de consolidación en la era uribe aunque sin mucho éxito. hoy sigue siendo uno de los que más ha aumentado en hectáreas de coca en el país además de uno donde más constantemente la fuerza pública hace incautaciones de material de guerra de las farc como el que realizó en febrero donde se encontraron kilos de explosivos. san vicente del caguán caquetáel municipio donde se ubicó la zona de distensión de las farc en los diálogos con el expresidente andrés pastrana vuelve a quedar entre los municipios protagonistas en este proceso. ha tenido presencia histórica de la columna teófilo forero de las farc que se financia sobre todo a través de la extorsión. de hecho este año se supo que la fiscalía tenía listas órdenes de captura para combatir a los encargados de cobrar las vacunas como contó semana. buenos aires caucaeste municipio del norte del departamento se llenó de periodistas hace un año luego de que las farc asesinaran mientras dormían a soldados. ese hecho hizo revertir la decisión de suspender los bombardeos contra la guerrilla y puso en jaque el proceso de paz. en marzo de este año los jefes de las farc marcos calarcá y pablo catatumbo fueron allí a hacer pedagogía de los acuerdos. hay presencia de coca sobre todo en los límites con el valle del cauca y minería ilegal de oro con minas pequeñas y medianas donde trabajan unos mil mineros. caldono caucacaldono ha sido víctima de las farc veces desde . la estación de policía ha sido destruida tres veces. aunque hay cultivos de coca son de baja densidad. el por ciento de la población es indígena. corinto caucacorinto es un municipio que sirve de corredor entre los ríos magdalena y cauca y por eso las farc se han ensañado allí. por ejemplo sólo en hubo una docena de hostigamientos y hasta ese año la guerrilla se lo había tomado siete veces. hasta según verdad abierta había habido masacres. hay algo de pequeña y mediana minería ilegal de material de construcción y de oro. la paz cesareste municipio de la serranía del perijá tuvo presencia y peleas por el territorio entre farc eln y los paramilitares. además hay al menos dos resguardos indígenas. uno de los corregimientos más azotadas por el conflicto es san josé de oriente que queda a sólo kilómetros de la frontera con venezuela y donde sólo hasta el volvió a instalarse una estación de policía. riosucio chocóeste municipio del urabá chocoano tiene una corta frontera con el chocó y una larga con antioquia. ha tenido presencia de guerrilla y paramilitares poblaciones indígenas y afro y graves problemas de necesidades básicas insatisfechas. tierralta córdobaaunque tierralta es conocido por haber alojado la concentración de los paramilitares en santa fe ralito ahora tendrá un campamento en la lejana vereda de el gallo donde hay presencia de las farc y de bacrim. el gallo queda junto a la represa de urrá y en el parque natural del nudo de paramillo que ha sido zona de refugio de grupos ilegales y corredor para el tráfico de armas y de drogas. puerto colombia guainíaeste corregimiento departamental una entidad que depende del departamento y no tiene alcalde propio es esencialmente selvático. con algunos cultivos de coca. en él como en buena parte de la amazonía hay amplios resguardos indígenas. fonseca guajiraese municipio de la zona de la guajira conocida como \"la provincia\" es conocido porque allí queda el corregimiento de conejo donde las farc hicieron proselitismo armado a inicios de . en su zona urbana hicieron presencia los paramilitares mientras que en la que queda en las estribaciones de la sierra del perijá hacían presencia las farc. san josé del guaviare guaviarela capital del guaviare y el único municipio que tendrá dos zonas de concentración es el décimo municipio con más coca sembrada en todo el país. en él han operado varios frentes como el séptimo. las farc dinamitaron la recientemente pavimentada carretera hacia el centro del país después de anunciar el cese al fuego unilateral en la macarena metauno de los municipios que conformó la zona de distensión que le entregó el gobierno de andrés pastrana a las farc entre y en él está buena parte del parque natural de la sierra de la macarena. mapiripán metaeste municipio que se hizo famoso por la masacre de paramilitares del urabá en tiene presencia de bandas criminales. hasta hace pocos años está conectada por vía pavimentada con villavicencio y san josé del guaviare. mesetas metamunicipio del ariari hizo parte de la zona de distensión que le entregó el gobierno de andrés pastrana a las farc entre y . como sus vecinos votó por el uribismo en y tiene cultivos ilícitos. vistahermosa metaeste municipio de la sierra de la macarena en el que queda parte del parque natural de ese nombre tiene una presencia tradicional de las farc y fue parte de la zona de distensión que le entregó el gobierno de andrés pastrana a las farc entre y . las farc no parecen tener mucha tracción política pues votó por el uribismo en . tiene cultivos de coca. policarpa nariñoun pequeño munuicipio andino pero con varios corregimientos en la selva pacífica en policarpa hubo presencia muy fuerte de las farc con el frente y los paramilitares con el frente libertadores del sur luengo la llamada ong y finalmente los rastrojos hasta el punto de que los dos atacaron en diferentes momentos el cuartel de policía y hace menos de año hubo desplazamientos grandes de las veredad de puerto rico montañita y campo alegre según verdad abierta. tumaco nariñotumaco el segundo puerto del país sobre el pacífico es el municipio con más cultivos de coca de todo el país y además sirve de corredor estratégico para organizaciones criminales pues es -al mismo tiempo- puerto de embarque frontera y centro de tráfico de insumos químicos para la producción de cocaína. y aunque hay presencia de bacrim las farc son más poderosas especialmente su columna móvil daniel aldana. tibú norte de santanderla capital del catatumbo es un tradicional pueblo petrolero. allí queda la gabarra un corregimiento conocido por una masacre paramilitar en y las farc hacen presencia especialmente en ese corregimiento y en otro llamado pacelli.
```

**What other strategies could I use?**

My dataframe contains 1200 rows, so I need a general approach that allows me to clean as much as possible. Although no all of the rows have messy data, a few of them do. The messy content comes mainly from interactive images of the website that I scraped the information (I could not skip them when scraping).

Comment: Have you considered fixing this when you do the scraping... using something like `rvest::html_text()` should remove all of the noise you have there from the start

Comment: @giocomai I used `rvest::html_text()` to scrape the data. The issue is how the website has been built. I could not get rid of the noise.